# Same unicode character behaves differently in different IDEs

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, netbeans, unicode

When I read the following unicode string it reads as differently..When I execute the program using netbeans it is working fine but when I tried using Eclipse / directly from CMD it is not working.

After reading it adds `ƒÂ` these characters

Then the string becomes `MÃƒÂ½xico`

String to be read is `MÃ½xico.`..I used the CSVReader with Encoding to read as follows.

```
    sourceReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(soureFile));
    List<String[]> data = sourceReader.readAll();
```

Any suggestions????????

Comment: It's not clear where the text is coming from, or where you're looking at the result. You say you're using "CSVReader with Encoding" - which encoding?

Comment: am using utf-8 encoding to read..updated the qn

Comment: And how are you observing that the string becomes something incorrect? Why is the string not "Mexico" with an appropriate accent to start with?

Comment: am just displaying it and found that it is reading as mentioned in the qn

Comment: Then don't "just display it" (whatever that means - in a console? In a Swing UI? Something else?) Instead, print out the individual character  values and the string length. Otherwise you're introducing the encoding of your output device as well.

Comment: Displaying in console..In netbeans it is working as expected..but in eclipse it is adding those extra characters..But after I did the clean and build to generate the jar file in netbeans.It is not working

Comment: Right, so as I said before, don't do that. Instead, iterate over the length of the string and print out the UTF-16 code unit for each `char`. That way you know *exactly* what the string looks like in memory. (As for not being able to reproduce this in netbeans with your jar file - it sounds like you have a lot of uncertainty at the moment, which we can't really help with easily...)

Comment: The reading code shown is fine.

It would be perfect style if you would use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `"UTF-8"` as the standard charsets need no handling of `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

It also seems the read file is in UTF-8.

So the writing to the console goes wrong. Mind, both IDEs have their pseudeo command line consoles.

Comment: Ok..let me try that..and I will update my findings

Comment: Sorry Jon Skeet / Joop Eggen...The statement to read is kept in different location..when i placed it in the correct location it is working fine every where...So the problem was I didnt set the encoding while reading..after setting the encoding it works fine..and thanks a lot for the immediate support...Thank you very much Jon Skeet ,Joop Eggen

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the different editors are using different encodings. For example one is using utf-8 and one is using something else.

Check the encoding settings in all of the editors are the same.

Answer (score 0):

We should use encoding while reading the file. So above statment should be changed as follows

```
    targetReader=new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(targetFile), "UTF-8"));
    data = targetReader.readAll();
```